# JSON deserialize insight into failure

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, gson

I am working on a system using a Spring Web MVC server. The browser client uploads a JSON data transfer object to the server to save.

The JSON is auto-deserialized using Jackson before the controller is called. The controller method has the deserialized object in its parameter list:

```
@RequestBody MyDto myDto,
```

It was working, but has now stopped. The problem is that the error messages don't give me any insight into what is failing.

I get this exception in my server output:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

I also tried changing the parameter to be a String instead of an object (@RequestBody String myDto). Then I used Gson instead of Jackson to see if it would either work or give any insight:

```
        try {
            MyDto dto = (new Gson().fromJson(MyDto, MyDto.class));
            log.debug(dto.toString());
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This doesn't throw any exception. It just creates a new MyDto object with all fields null.

I guess I changed something in the object and it can't be deserialized from the JSON string until I make the change there. I have seen this scenario a few times before with trivial objects. When I had a closer look there was always a field mismatch. In this case, MyDto is a bigger object, and a subclass of other objects.

Is there any way to get Jackson or Gson to tell me what fields are causing the failure?

Comment: Looks to me like it's saying JSON isn't supported.

Comment: Please show us your full code to help identify the issue.

Comment: You should show us exactly how you send the object. I'm sure you just have a typo in the Context-Type field of your request.

Comment: I figured it out. 

MyDto is a class that contains other data transfer objects. One of those was not marked as serializable. 

Still, jackson should give an error message that points to the problem. So I'm leaving the question unanswered in the hope that someone can advise a way to get intelligible output from jackson and not need to check every part of the object hierarchy.